# How to draw a rectangle in pinescript v4

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I tried to create a rectangle using this code in pinescript v.4:

```
b = box.new(bar_index[100], highest(high,50), bar_index[10], lowest(low, 50), color.purple, 1, line.style_solid, extend.none, xloc.bar_index, color.new(color.purple, 90))
box.delete(b[1])
```

but getting error:

```
The 'resolution' argument is incompatible with functions that have side effects.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution argument of the `study()` function is not compatible with the functions with side effects - drawings, `alert()` function calls etc.

In Pine Script v5, the `resolution=` parameter has been renamed `timeframe=` and this aspect is explicitly highlighted in the manual:

> timeframe (const string) Adds multi-timeframe functionality to simple
> scripts. When used, a "Timeframe" field will be added to the script's
> "Settings/Inputs" tab. ... **The parameter cannot be used with
> scripts using Pine Script® drawings**.

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_indicator

Remove the `resolution=` and `resolution_gaps=` parameters from `study()` function call to be able to draw on the chart (boxes, lines, tables etc).

Comment: hes in version 4

Comment: The v4 manual did not address this issue, but the same restriction applies to the v4 `resolution` parameter - either the script can use the resolution parameter or the drawing functions, but not both at the same time.

Comment: hey, thats good to know